# Can I install LAMP and some IDE on my USB device?

Tags: installation, security, usb-drive

Actually I am using a shared pc, and I want to know, if there is a way That I can install applications on my PEN DRIVE or EXTERNAL HARD. Like LMAP, Netbeans and some other for the web development. 
Or are there other ways to keep my data safe if someone scans the pc for what I am doing. It is a sort of SECRET Operation :)

All Suggestions and Solutions will be very help full. 
Thanks.

Comment: Come on guys... Haven't any one tried this. Or I'm just thinking too much :)

Answer (score 1):

Install a LiveCD distribution on your USB stick and boot the PC using this USB stick. Some LiveCD distributions are easily customizable so you that can include LAMP/IDE in them.

If booting on the USB stick is not an option, please tell us which OS/version the PC is running.

The most reliable is probably to store a VM image on the USB stick, but that might be slow to start/run/stop.

Answer (score 0):

USB drives are easily lost and thus rather insecure. If security is what you're looking for, you should be using encryption.

As far as making a stand-alone installation goes, I don't know too much about doing that in Linux. However, if you've got a removable drive (hard drive, flash drive, etc.) that you can format to some Linux-native format (such as ext3 or ext4), and if you can have the drive accessible every time you install a new version, you can employ symlinks to suit your purposes:

1. Check whether a particular software can be installed to an arbitrary location. If so, do so. Otherwise:
2. Install the desired software via package manager such as Synaptic.
3. Use the package manager's tools to get a list of installed files.
4. Copy every installed file and directory to your external drive.
5. Make symlinks from each original location to the external drive.
6. Hope that the affected software doesn't freak out because of the symlinks.